# Android: Download personal's information from server

Tags: android, image, parsing, android-studio, download

I have 2 questions. 
First I am working on an application that gets persons' information from my server so what is the best way to get images from server.

Second should i download images to my storages and then recieve them from my phone's storage to my application. Thank you in advance.

Edit :

I want to do that with all information i parse such as phone number, gender... So what should i do exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exist a lot of libraries that can be used for loading the images from server.

Listing out some of them

1. [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
2. [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Most of the image loading libraries provide caching mechanism, so that there is no need to store the images over phone's storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries like "Fresco" or "Picaso" for this. With the help of this you can set images in your app directly from server using image Uri. So you dont have to download it seperately and to stored it in your device.

Answer (score 0):

You should not store images in data storage instead of trying to get images from url.

Please see the below link :

http://negativeprobability.blogspot.in/2011/08/lazy-loading-of-images-in-listview.html